# Lo4j config - Log to different files based on type of mesasge prefix

Tags: log4j2

Hello I am using Log4j2 for my logging and I am little confused as to how I can log message to a different file based on the message prefix.

For example, currently all messages are logged in a single logs folder.
A set of my messages look like this:
'com.project.latency: ProjectName=[MooPointProject].......'

Some of my other log messages are of the format:
'com.project.latency: ProjectName=[DataPlaneProject].......'

I want to log the messages which contain the MooPointProject in a specific file and one containing DataPlaneProject in a separate log file.

Is there a specific way I can do that other than changing the logging level itself?

Comment: @Alexey should be selected as best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up several appenders one for each project name. For example:

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/MooPointProject.log"
             filePattern="logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz">
  <RegexFilter regex=".*MooPointProject.*" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
  <PatternLayout>
    <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
  <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
</RollingFile>
```

and

```
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/DataPlaneProject.log"
             filePattern="logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz">
  <RegexFilter regex=".*DataPlaneProject.*" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
  <PatternLayout>
    <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
  <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
</RollingFile>
```

Then assign both the appenders to your logger(s). Since your `RegexpFilter` accepts only a project-spcific lines you will get them to the appropriate files separately.

P.S. - Find the detail on other types of filters [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/filters.html).